# How do I clone a github repo to a certain branch in my repo

Tags: github

I'm trying to upload a folder that includes over 100 files. So I'm thinking about getting the repo that already has that folder and cloning it into the branch I want the folder in.

Answer (score 1):

You can't clone a repo into a branch. You clone a repo. Period.

Just like in the real world, if you clone something you get a copy of the original. If you clone a sheep, you get a sheep, not a cow. If you clone a repo, you get a repo, not a branch.

Comment: then is there a way to bypass the 100 files limit

Comment: Also, if there is a way to clone a branch into a branch that could work too,